# How to implement Oath2.0 with Express and React Router?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have SPA that uses express as a backend. I'm trying to implement OAuth2 for authentication but I'm a little stuck on how React Router is supposed to communicate with the backend.

This is what I have so far. I didn't include the session or CORS configuration but I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Express:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await userQueries.getUserById(id);
  return done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
  {
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback",
  }, 
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const email = profile.emails[0].value;
    const existingUser = await userQueries.getUser(email);
    if (existingUser) {
      console.log(`user: ${existingUser.name} successfully retrieved`);
      done(null, existingUser);
    } else {
      new User({
        name: profile.displayName,
        email,
      })
        .save()
        .then((newUser) => {
          console.log("new user created using Google OAuth 2.0");
          done(null, newUser);
      });
    }
  }
)

app.get("auth/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] }));
app.get("auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"), handleLogin);
```

The second get request is the redirect URI that I inputted into Google.

In my react code, I have a button with an `onClick` handler that calls a function with a fetch request to the the first get request. This is what it looks like:

```
function googleLogin() {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/auth/google", {
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      })
      .then((res) => {
        res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
          sessionStorage.setItem("username", data.username);
          navigate("/host");
        }
      });
  }
```

The handleLogin middleware then sends a response to the client which when received notifies React Router to navigate to a new URL.

I keep getting an error saying that the issue is with CORS and that I need an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header but I think there's a deeper problem. I'm making a fetch request to "/auth/google" and expecting a response from the redirect URI, "auth/google/callback." Therefore I think CORS is blocking the response from the "auth/google" route because that shouldn't be accessible to the browser but what I really need is the response from the "auth/google/callback route after the redirect is made.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding how a redirect URI works. Google will call your redirect URI, and then you need your API to take that response, save the credentials, then you can redirect back to your front end page. Either that or you need to make your redirect URI your front-end, and pick apart the parameters to then send back to your API or store in session like you are currently doing.

Although maybe i'm just not following your flow properly.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. I'm using React and React Router so part of my authorization for this app includes using state in React. When a user is successfully authenticated, the server sends a response to the browser which sets the `loggedIn` state to `true` then React Router navigates them to another page. That's what the `handleLogin` middleware does. I set the redirect URI to a backend route which includes the `handleLogin` middleware which sends a response telling React to set the `loggedIn` state to `true`. The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve that response due to the redirect.